# Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and I want there reference between the two.

I tried using the alter table command, but it gives me an error, can anyone help me please?

```
CREATE TABLE `registos` (
`data_registo` char(10) NOT NULL,
`hora_registo` time NOT NULL,
`idSensor` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
`Temperatura` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`Humidade` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`pt_orvalho` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`idRegisto` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`idRegisto`,`idSensor`,`data_registo`,`hora_registo`),
KEY `fk_registos_sensores1_idx` (`idSensor`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_registos_sensores1` FOREIGN KEY (`idSensor`) REFERENCES `sensores`   (`idSensor`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 )




CREATE TABLE `alarmes` (
`idAlarme` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`descricao_alarme` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`data_criacao` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`idRegisto` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idAlarme`,`idRegisto`)
)
```

---

```
ALTER TABLE alarmes

ADD CONSTRAINT FK_alarmes1
FOREIGN KEY (idRegisto) REFERENCES registos(idRegisto)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `idRegisto` as a signed integer in one table and an unsigned integer in the other table. Foreign key references can only be made between fields with the same type.

Another problem is that you created the table with the name `registos` but you are trying to add a key referencing the table `registo`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I copy an old script...I edit code, but give me same error :(

Comment: @user3320956 Post the edit you've made in your question. We're not going to guess what you edited.

Comment: @user3320956 See my edit. It works fine for me with both the field type and table name corrected.

Comment: You have right..I change code, and tested, but give me the same error :( I don't understand...